# Let $T$ be the following set of ordered triplets,$T=\{(a,b,c):a,b,c\in N\}$. Find the number of elements in $T$ such that $L.C.M(a,b,c)=72$.

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, permutations, combinations

Let $T$ be the following set of ordered triplets,$T=\{(a,b,c):a,b,c\in N\}$. Find the number of elements in $T$ such that $L.C.M(a,b,c)=72$.

**My Attempt**
Let $a=2^{x_1}3^{y_1}$,$b=2^{x_2}3^{y_2}$ and $c=2^{x_3}3^{y_3}$

The $x_i's$ have 4 choices each where at least one of them should have the value $3$
and the rest can take any value from $0$ to $4$. This can be done in $3\times 4\times 4=48$ ways

Similarly for $y_i's$ we have $3$ choices for each. This can be done in $27$ ways .

So required number of ways =$48\times 27=1245$ ways.

Is this correct

Comment: I feel it's fine, but you have a typo : "The $x_i$s have $4$ choices each where at least one of them should have the value $3$ and the rest can take any value from $0$ to $\color{green}{3}$".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $3$ possible values for the exponent of $3$ in $A,B,C$ but at least one must take the maximal value of $2$. So there are $3^3 - 2^3 = 27-8 = 19$ possibilities.

Similarly for the exponents of $2$ there are $4^3 - 3^3 = 37$ possibilities.

$37*19 = 703$

Comment: That was crisp!